# Testing if another method on same object was called with testing the targetObject

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

```
public Class Test{
   GetDataset(RandomBoolean uncertain);
   GetDataset2();
   GetDataset3();
}
```

where method definitions are

```
    public virtual void GetDataset2(){}
    public virtual void GetDataset3(){}

    public virtual void GetDataset(RandomBoolean uncertain)
    {
     if (uncertain.State){
            GetDataset2();
    }
     else{
       GetDataset3();
     }
    }

    //mocking uncertain.State to return true
    //ACT
    testObject.GetDataset(uncertainMock);
```

I want to test if GetDataset2() was called internally when I act on testObject.GetDataset();
I am not mocking the testObject because it's the test object so if I try to do

```
testObject.AssertWasCalled(x => x.GetDataset2());
```

It won't let me do this because testObject is not a mocked object.
I am using Rhino Mocks 3.5, I am definitely missing something here. 
What is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Also I want to do it in AAA and not the old syntax.

Comment: After reading the below two answers, I have modified the code a bit, to make it more clear and to ask a cascading question.
What I understand from below answers so far is that, in GetDataset(int a), all I can do is to check that uncertain.State was used and I can not test if the decision made on this was correct or not. 
Which means if some other developer later swaps the two methods and since I won't have any unit tests checking the behaviour so I won't know it broke.

Comment: I asked this question because I was under assumption that I can partically mock the test object itself and see if its other methods are called, I didn't knew how to do that with AAA in 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't. On the other thing usually you don't want to. When you are unit testing the class, you want to make sure that the class does its computation correctly and that it has correct side effects. You shouldn't test the internals of the class, because this causes the coupling of the real code and the tests to be too strong. The idea is that you can freely change the implementation of your class and use your tests to make sure it still works correctly. You wouldn't be able to do it if your tests inspect the internal state or flow.

You have 2 options (depending on context)

1. You can structure your tests in a way that they only look at externally visible behaviour
2. If (1) is too hard, consider refactoring GetDataset2 into a separate class. Then you would be able to mock it while testing GetDataset method.

Answer (score 0):

That's generally not how unit testing with mocks works.

You should be concerned with collaborators (which you stub/mock) and with results (state changes in the case of `void` methods), not with the internal workings of the system under test (calls to collaborators notwithstanding).

That is both because and why you can't make those types of behavioural observations (at least not without changing your classes to accommodate testing, by exposing private members or adding state-revealing members -- not good ideas).

Answer (score 0):

There is some info about partial mocks [here](http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). Here are some [code snippets](http://elegantcode.com/2008/04/08/partial-mocks-explained/) on how to do that with RhinoMocks and Moq.

Try this:

```
using Rhino.Mocks;
public class TestTest {
 [Test]
 public void FooTest()
 {
   var mock = new MockRepository().PartialMock<Test>();
   mock.Expect(t => t.GetDataset2());

   mock.GetDataset((RandomBoolean)null);

 }
}
```

Comment: This is not AAA syntax AFAIK.

Comment: Updated again. Give that a go.

Comment: This is old syntax again, I was chasing it in the rhinomocks google group and found a reply saying "With the release of rhino 3.6 you should be able to do Partials using 
AAA syntax (that is without the creation of a MockRepository)"
http://groups.google.com/group/rhinomocks/browse_thread/thread/abcd31795ef4b0e2/fa43a26d815efc5e?lnk=gst&q=Override+stub#fa43a26d815efc5e

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a partial mock via Rhino Mocks, you could also create class derived from Test that replaces the implementation of GetDataSet2() with a function that records it was called.  Then check that in your test.

It is a code smell that you're doing too much in one class though.